# Two screens/monitors with Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, android-hardware, multiscreen

I want to develop an Android application which uses two screens to display information. For example: One screens shows the app, the other screen some information about the current app status.

My question: Does android support two monitors/screens? How would you build up such a device and project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show different content on the Android's screen and the screen connected via HDMI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470668/is-it-possible-to-show-different-content-on-the-androids-screen-and-the-screen)

Answer (score 4):

From API level 17, android supports this

Here is the link
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation

It is now possible for an APP to independently draw different content on primary and secondary displays. Secondary displays can be an HDMI screen or a wireless display.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices do.  For example the HTC Evo has a micro-HDMI output that you can send to a TV but the functionality is not built into the Android core so you would need to use the proprietary extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do it using widgets.
There is no other way. I have researched on this and there happens to be lot of problems. One company has successfully done it but they could not port two opengl instances.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Kyocera Echo and Dual-screen SDK for Gingerbread](http://www.echobykyocera.com/developers/sdk-tools/)!